# How can I do FloydSteinbergAlpha dithering with ImageMagick?

Tags: imagemagick

I just changed all of my images to RGBA4444 using TexturePacker for spritesheets and ImageMagick for individual images.

Is it possible to do FloydSteinbergAlpha dithing with ImageMagick? I could only find FloydSteinberg dithering (i.e., without the alpha).

My options are -depth 4 -dither FloydSteinberg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would apply `-dither` when dropping color count, along with pixel depth (see [Quantization Colors](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/quantize/#colors)).

```
convert source.png -colors 64 -dither None out.png
convert source.png -colors 64 -dither FloydSteinberg out.png
convert source.png -colors 64 -dither Riemersma out.png
```

[image: 64 color dither]

For pixel depth of 4, we can assume [image: 2^4 = 16]

```
convert source.png -depth 4 -colors 16 -dither None out.png
convert source.png -depth 4 -colors 16 -dither FloydSteinberg out.png
convert source.png -depth 4 -colors 16 -dither Riemersma out.png
```

[image: 4-bit depth with dither]

### Edit

To include alpha in the dithering, set the [-quantize](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php?#quantize) to transparent

```
convert source.png \
        -quantize transparent \
        -dither FloydSteinberg \
        -depth 4 -colors 16 \
        out.png
```

[image: dither with transparent]

Comment: I am already dithering. I am looking for the option to involve alpha in the dithering algorithm: i.e., -dither FloydSteinbergAlpha vs  -dither FloydSteinberg

Comment: Answer updated. There is no FloydSteinbergAlpha enumerator, so searching for it will go nowhere. But what you want is covered in depth by the [documentation](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/quantize/#color_trans).